# How do you lazy load a single component in Angular2 (RC5)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been able to get lazy loading to work with NgModules using the prescribed loadChildren attribute of the Route.

```
import {RouterModule} from ‘@angular/router’
import {NgModule} from ‘@angular/core’
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent, MyHomeRoute ],
  bootstrap: [ MyComponent ],
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot([
     { path: ‘home’, component: MyHomeRoute },
     { path: ‘lazy’, loadChildren: ‘./my-lazy-module’ }
  ])
})
class MyAppModule {}
```

But is there a way to configure a Route to lazy load a single component (as opposed to an NgModule) using a string for the "component" attribute?

I always end up geting errors like:
**"Cannot resolve component using 'lazyComponent'"**

Comment: You can move the component to its own module.

Comment: well...i know that.  It just seems like more unnecessary "boilerplating" if its only to wrap one component. Are you saying this is the only way to do it?  Because I see that the "component" property of a Route is allowed to be a string, so it seems like perhaps there was the intention for lazy loading of a component to work.

Comment: That was the way before RC.5. I don't know if thus is still supposed to work.

Comment: Hi, have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then load on demand:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
 const routes: Routes= [{path: 'welcome', loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module'}];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

here: loadChildren: 'app/screens/welcome.module' is ts file app/screens/welcome.module.ts

For more detail example, checked this: http://plnkr.co/edit/18CZVF?p=preview

Comment: same solution that @GunterZochbauer recommended.

Comment: Plunkr file does not do anything when clicking the links within it